# How to sync or share a text to google doc

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, google-docs

Ha ii,I am doing a Bible application,my requirement is the user write a note or copy some contents in Bible have to sync or share with google doc.Is there any API available for this ?like sharing to Facebook or twitter.
How to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you can share from your iOS to Facebook using [**Facebook iOS SDK**](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), also see [**here**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/).

From iOS 5, Twitter is integrated deeply into the SDK. So you could potentially leverage that to share. I don't think as of now, Twitter provides an SDK for iOS...

**UPDATE:** 
To share in Google reader, you could try - [sharekit](http://getsharekit.com/). But for other google services, you need to implement the oAuth flow yourself & then you'll be able to post stuff there...

Best of luck...

Comment: ,I know how to share with Facebook and twitter,my need is to share with google doc.

Comment: ooh, then you could try - http://getsharekit.com/

Comment: so thre is no api for this right?

Comment: not that I know of. You can add one yourself in `getsharekit`. Go through their documentation...